# Errro con Case y multiples condiciones

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql, usecase

Estoy tratando de hacer una condición con varias variables, sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 104
Incorrect syntax near 'CODIFICACION_CLIENTE'
```

Este es mi código:

```
SELECT clienteid,   
    CASE
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 0 AND Monto_total_Promedio <= 1250 AND CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = 'F' THEN 'A'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 1250 AND Monto_total_Promedio <= 2500 AND CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = 'F' THEN 'B'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 2500 AND Monto_total_Promedio <= 3750 CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = 'F' THEN 'C'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 5000 AND CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = 'F' THEN 'D'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 0 AND Monto_total_Promedio <= 2500 AND CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = 'J' THEN 'A'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 2500 AND Monto_total_Promedio <= 5000 AND CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = 'J' THEN 'B'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 5000 AND Monto_total_Promedio <= 7500 CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = 'J' THEN 'C'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 10000 AND CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = 'J' THEN 'D'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 0 AND Monto_total_Promedio <= 1250 AND CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = '#N/A' THEN 'A'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 1250 AND Monto_total_Promedio <= 2500 AND CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = '#N/A' THEN 'B'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 2500 AND Monto_total_Promedio <= 3750 CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = '#N/A' THEN 'C'
WHEN Monto_total_Promedio > 5000 AND CODIFICACION_CLIENTE = '#N/A' THEN 'D'
END AS NUEVO_PATRON_CLIENTE 
FROM CLIENTES_TOTALES
ORDER BY clienteid
```

Si lo hago sin el CODIFICACION_CLIENTE no me genera error, pero con él me genera ese error. Llevo rato probando y buscando pero en todo lado que consulto parece estar bien.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la estructura de tu tabla? De esa forma podríamos apoyarte con mayor certeza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error está en esta varias de estas lineas:

```
Monto_total_Promedio <= 3750 CODIFICACION_CLIENTE
```

Agrega el AND entre Monto_total_Promedio y CODIFICACION_CLIENTE, y eso debería de solucionar tu problema